# How to auto populate data from CSV files to PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, csv

i`m using this SQL query to populate a database:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_x AS SELECT * FROM testcsv LIMIT 0; -- but see below

COPY tmp_x FROM 'D:\water_utility.csv' (header, FORMAT CSV, ENCODING 'WIN1251');

insert into testcsv select * from (
select x.* 
from tmp_x x
left outer join testcsv t on t. timestamp = x. timestamp
where t. timestamp is null
) as missing;

DROP TABLE tmp_x; -- else it is dropped at end of session automatically
```

Can you help me by giving advice how to get all files from folder named like this and populate the table with data:

> sample_1.csv sample_2.csv ... sample_12.csv

The numbers are the months that are created the files. How to create auto populate script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try smth like:

```
do
$$
begin
 execute format ($f$COPY tmp_x FROM 'D:\water_utility%s.csv' (header, FORMAT CSV, ENCODING 'WIN1251');$f$,extract(month from now()));
end;
$$
;
```

instead of your copy line.

**update**
it is often called dynamic sql - I format the statement before calling it. here I append the current month number to the name of the file, so the line execute would be:

```
COPY tmp_x FROM 'D:\water_utility8.csv' (header, FORMAT CSV, ENCODING 'WIN1251');
```

because August is 8th month (which I get with `extract(month from now())`)

Comment: Can you explain the code i cant understand it on 100%, please?

Comment: Thanks for the great help! Cheers!

Comment: Hello again. Can you help me again. I want to the same and for the year. How to accomplish this?

Comment: hi, please post a new question  instead

Comment: i think i will have a lot of negative votes because of duplicate the question.

Comment: if you can't adapt this post for a new task yourself, please create  new post with full description of what needs to be done - if the post gets closed for duplicate - does not it release all downvotes?.. anyway - SO is not meant to expand support to the post in comments - sorry

Comment: No, it does not release all downvotes. But i managed to edit the code and now i can change dynamically the year too. :)